# How to make next/image fill available grid space?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

How do I make `next/image` span from grid 1 through 8? When I try it with `img` tag it works but with `next/image` it doesn't.

```css
.project {
  display: grid;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
}

.project-img {
  grid-column: 1 / span 8;
  grid-row: 1 / 1;
  height: 30rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
}
```

```
<article className='project'>
  <img
    src={img}
    className='project-img'
    alt={title}
    height='100%'
    width='100%'
  />
  <div className='project-info'>....</div>
</article>
```

---

#### Using `next/image`

[image]

#### Using `img` tag

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I believe you have a few solutions here. First let me recommend that you spend a little time practicing with css grid on [this](https://cssgridgarden.com/) website, it's very helpful. The first solution i see is that your row starts and ends at the same "box". That shouldn't be the case. It should end at 2 because that specifies the "box" it ends at but doesn't include. The second solution is to use the `grid-area` property on this `next/image` you want to style. That would look like this:

```css
.project-image{
  grid-area: 1/1/2/8;
}
```

This specifies that the row starts at 1, column starts at 1, row ends at 1, column ends at 8. You could also break the `grid-area` property up into it's composite properties, `grid-row-start`, `grid-column- start`, `grid-row-end`, and `grid-column-end`. That would look like this:

```
.project-image{
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 8; 
}
```

If wether or not one of those solutions works for you, I encourage you to check out that website. If my answers didn't work, I guarantee that you will find a solution there! If my answers do work it'll still solidify the concept of css grid for you.